# Android keyboard slides down leaving white space behind screen (Using Fragement)

Tags: android

My Problem have been explained on below url

[Android keyboard slides down leaving white space behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395570/android-keyboard-slides-down-leaving-white-space-behind)

http://www.flickr.com/photos/54884891@N05/10310528196/

But this answers are not working for me. I am using Fragment ,Where i have search edit text . Whenever keypad is coming up and going down this is always leaving dirty white space.

Thanks in Advance,,

Answer (score 6):

You should use " **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"** " in your Manifest file.